# A term describing children raised in a single parent household?

Tags: terminology

Since there are terms describing children born during some periods, like millennials, or with some ethnicities, like African American, or how long they've stayed in the US, like first generation immigrant, or those who have experienced a lot, like a third culture kid. Is there a term for children raised in a single parent household? I know there are single parent, single mom, single dad, how about the children?

Comment: Sadly, "disadvantaged" comes to mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply say ***single-parent*** children or ***single-parented*** children:

1. The **single-parented** child has become a focal point of attention for many educators (https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/dissertations/2222/).
2. **Single-parent** children behavior... (https://www.privatewriting.com/blog/single-parent-children-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

An orphan is someone whose parents have died; when the responsibility of nurturing a child is borne by a single parent it could be said that the child is either [**motherless**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/motherless) or [**fatherless**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fatherless), although many would presume that he or she is orphaned of a parent. The expression is used by an author whose  biological father had not deceased

> My mother got full custody of me, and I later learned that my father had a habit of driving to St. Louis, then up and down my grandparents’ street, hoping to see me. My grandmother was adamant—she sent him away. I remember his arriving only one time. Perhaps I was seven. I was happy to see him, …. I sat on his lap on the front porch of my grandparents’ house for a bit while he chatted with my grandfather in the other chair. ….
>
> As the years went by, I stopped listening to stories about my father, stopped paying attention to the murmurs of compassion for me as **a fatherless girl**. I took my uncle to father-daughter night at school, and I viewed the fathers of my friends with some skepticism—….
>
> *[My Absent Father](https://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/absent-father)*
>   <sub>By Jane Smiley, October 3, 2014</sub>

The formal equivalents would be *maternal orphan*, and *paternal orphan*. If a child never sees a parent, even if he or she is alive, that child to all intents and purposes is a **half-orphan**. A writer might prefer this term for its emotional impact on the reader. Whereas an adult might arrive at this logical conclusion after a dispassionate analysis.

An **absent father** or **absent mother** is a biological parent who is still alive but sporadically or rarely participates in their child's life.

> **Absent parents**
>   Parenting can be a little more challenging when there isn’t another parent around to help you share the load.  This can be because of a variety of reasons, *[perhaps the absent parent has died, is in prison, or lives in another country or you don’t know where the father is](https://www.familylives.org.uk/advice/your-family/single-parents/absent-parents/)*.
>
> FamilyLives.org.uk

Comment: All the sources I looked at for 'half-orphan' specified that one parent be dead, do you have a source to back up its use for where the parent is alive, but absent? It's difficult to see how the term can be other than misleading and potentially offensive if use to describe people whose parents merely live apart.

Comment: @Spagirl I specifically said if the child *never* sees a parent for all intents and purposes that child is a half-orphan. I provided "absent father/mother" in the scenario when a biological parent is alive but does not  participate regularly in their child's life.

Comment: Declaring a living parent 'effectively dead to you' is an extremely personal statement/action from any child who has a living parent they don't see for whatever reason. It may be reasonable to use the term with regard to a child who you know has made that statement, but otherwise it would risk treading into very sensitive territory. I think it is an unfortunate inclusion in an otherwise useful and backed-up answer.

Comment: Whoever said, "effectively dead to you"? Where did I say that? I'm merely pointing out a fact. Growing with only one parent, and one parent only is like being a half-orphan. A single-parented child can grow with two parents who are both involved in their life, but that child lives with only one parent. That answer was supplied by Enguroo. My answer covers the instances when one parent is "missing" either permanently or frequently.

Comment: I din't intend to imply you said it. My understanding was that if a non-orphan-in-any-degree-child is for 'all intents and purposes' a half-orphan, then *that child* must regard themself as such, and if they don't then it would be horrible and confusing for them to be described that way and misleading for others hearing the term used who may make unwarranted assumptions. The OP is asking for words to use about people, people may have a response to the words used to describe them and that should be considered in recommending terms. This one may well be offensive.

Comment: @Spagirl  How is growing up never seeing, never having any contact with a biological parent, who is alive and well, any better than growing up without a mother or father? I would say the former is far more harmful and hurtful than the latter, at least in the death of a parent a child can learn to accept and understand that parent's absence. Anyway, I am not forcing anyone to choose one term over the other. The OP may well prefer single-parented, and that is fine by me.

Comment: I haven’t made any claims for a situation regarding parents being better or worse. What I did was suggest that an otherwise helpful answer is spoiled by implausible claims for the appropriateness of the term ‘half orphan’. If you’d felt able to edit I would upvote, but I can see that isn’t how you feel so I am instead downvoting for the reasons which I’ve tried to explain.